# Laravel relationship with a join

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following scenario. `Employer` model has a method called **offers**:

```
public function offers()
{
    $offers = $this->hasMany(Offer::class)
        ->join('employers', 'offers.employer_id', '=', 'employers.id')
        ->join('recruiting_events', 'recruiting_events.id', '=', 'offers.recruiting_event_id');
    switch (request()->input('show')) {
        case 'future':
            $offers->where('recruiting_events.date', '<', DB::raw('NOW()'));
            break;
        case 'current':
        default:
            $offers->where('recruiting_events.date', '>=', DB::raw('NOW()'));
            break;
    }
    return $offers;
}
```

It checks whether the request has a parameter show and filters the data based on it. So far, so good - `Employer::find(1)->offers` works perfectly.

However if I want to get all employers that have offers I get an SQL error:

`Employer::whereHas('offers')->get();`

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'web_recruiting_events.date' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `web_employers` where exists (select * from `web_galleries` where `web_galleries`.`galleriable_id` = `web_employers`.`id` and `web_galleries`.`galleriable_type` = App\Models\Employer) and exists (select * from `web_offers` where `web_offers`.`employer_id` = `web_employers`.`id` and `web_recruiting_events`.`date` < NOW() and `web_offers`.`deleted_at` is null))

Why doesn't it execute the `join` clause, but the `where` is OK?

Comment: First rule: you should not use logic in your Model, based on request.

Comment: It's checking for that `where` inside the `exists` clause. Definitely rethink your logic here.

Comment: Start by creating two separate relationships `futureOffers()` and `currentOffers()`. Get rid of the joins entirely.